# Loop animation once in LibGDX

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I have an explosion animation i need to loop once and then dissapear, but is not working,
This part its supposed to do the trick: `birdAnimationHit.setPlayMode(Animation.NORMAL);`

But it only shows the last image of the loop. Don't know what is wrong, here is my code

AssetLoader.java

```
public static void load() {
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    dustHit1 = new TextureRegion(texture, 930, 154, 140, 158);
    dustHit1.flip(false, true);

    dustHit2 = new TextureRegion(texture, 1079, 154, 187, 158);
    dustHit2.flip(false, true);

    dustHit3 = new TextureRegion(texture, 1274, 154, 149, 158);
    dustHit3.flip(false, true);

    dustHit4 = new TextureRegion(texture, 1430, 154, 153, 158);
    dustHit4.flip(false, true);

    dustHit5 = new TextureRegion(texture, 1590, 154, 155, 158);
    dustHit5.flip(false, true);

    TextureRegion[] birdsHit = { dustHit1, dustHit2, dustHit3, dustHit4, dustHit5 };
    birdAnimationHit = new Animation(0.06f, birdsHit);
    birdAnimationHit.setPlayMode(Animation.NORMAL);
}
```

GameRenderer.java

```
private void drawBirdHit(float runTime) {

    batcher.draw(birdAnimationHit.getKeyFrame(runTime), bird.getX(),
            bird.getY(), bird.getWidth() / 2.0f,
            bird.getHeight() / 2.0f, bird.getWidth(), bird.getHeight(),
            1.4f, 1.4f, bird.getRotation());

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sum up the runTime inside of that logic. Else you always get the same frame. Take a look at the getKeyFrame method: (Marked the importend part for you)

```
public TextureRegion getKeyFrame (float stateTime) {
    int frameNumber = getKeyFrameIndex(stateTime);
    return keyFrames[frameNumber];
}

public int getKeyFrameIndex (float stateTime) {
    if (keyFrames.length == 1) return 0;

    int frameNumber = (int)(stateTime / frameDuration); //this will always produce the same picture if you dont sum up the time!
    switch (playMode) {
    case NORMAL:
    frameNumber = Math.min(keyFrames.length - 1, frameNumber);
    break;
    case LOOP:
    frameNumber = frameNumber % keyFrames.length;
    break;
    case LOOP_PINGPONG:
    frameNumber = frameNumber % ((keyFrames.length * 2) - 2);
    if (frameNumber >= keyFrames.length) frameNumber = keyFrames.length - 2 - (frameNumber - keyFrames.length);
    break;
    case LOOP_RANDOM:
    frameNumber = MathUtils.random(keyFrames.length - 1);
    break;
    case REVERSED:
    frameNumber = Math.max(keyFrames.length - frameNumber - 1, 0);
    break;
    case LOOP_REVERSED:
    frameNumber = frameNumber % keyFrames.length;
    frameNumber = keyFrames.length - frameNumber - 1;
    break;
    }
    return frameNumber;
}
```

So hold somewhere a timer where you sumup the deltatimes

and change your code to something like this:

```
private void drawBirdHit(float runTime) {
    sum += runTime;
    batcher.draw(birdAnimationHit.getKeyFrame(sum), bird.getX(),
            bird.getY(), bird.getWidth() / 2.0f,
            bird.getHeight() / 2.0f, bird.getWidth(), bird.getHeight(),
            1.4f, 1.4f, bird.getRotation());
}
```

The Animation itself does not have a timer for that. You can just request the right keyframe depending on the past time, not on the current deltatime.

Comment: I added the sum variable to my code, but have no clue what to do where you say "hold somewhere a timer where you sumup the deltatimes"

Comment: If you added the sum variable as member it should work and you would be done with the bug. Simply hold a float member variable inside of your class where you use the animation (sum) where you sum up the runTime. This is the variable you need to pass to the `getKeyFrame method`

Answer (score 2):

What I do is simply include a blank frame as the last frame of any animation; you only need one per sprite sheet that can be used for multiple animations. Then just call the stop/play methods, the animation will run then disappear, ready for the next play on collision or whatever.